# Rails Way for dynamic link_to

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have a drop-down that users can choose what template they are about to receive. I'm pretty novice to Rails but I kind of go the logic `Front-end = JavaScript` and that's what I did, but *this* use of JavaScript seems like Rails should be able to handles it.

```
    <div class="form-group">
        <%= form_tag %>
            <%= select_tag :statement_type, options_for_select(Statement.statement_types.keys.to_a), :class => 'id_select', :id => 'secret_id'  %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
        <%= link_to "New Form", new_statement_template_path(:statement_type => 'SoW'), :id => "secret_submit", method: :post %>
  </div>
```

The -only- purpose of the `form_tag` is because I couldn't get the `link_to` to successfully launch other-wise.

I make the link dynamic by using this function

```
$('#secret_id').on('change', function(){
    $('#secret_submit').attr('href', '/statements/new/statement_type='+ $('#secret_id').val());
});
```

I of course now have a pretty ugly URL, and in addition had to create a custom route, so I am wondering about the 'Rails Way' of doing this. Or at the least, making the URL prettier.

Answer (score 1):

Your `link_to` is set to POST but you are adding the `statement_type` on the url like if it were a GET request? Sounds like you are mixing things and you can resolve this using just a single form element without JS if I understand you right.

```
<%= form_tag new_statement_template_path, method: :post %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= select_tag :statement_type, options_for_select(Statement.statement_types.keys.to_a) %>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
    <%= submit_tag "New Form" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Now your controller action will have a the selected option at `params[:statement_type]`.

Answer (score 0):

This looks incomplete, but the first thing is that you shouldn't need the form tag. A link tag cannot be set dynamically but you could set the window location. For example:

```
<select id='secret_id'>
  <option value="1">First Type</option>
  <option value="2">Second Type</option>
  <option value="3">Third Type</option>" 
</select>

$('#secret_id').on('change', function() { 
  var statement_type = $('#secret_id').val();
  var href =  '/statements/' + statement_type + '/new';
  window.location = href;
});
```

also, without seeing your code, it shouldn't be necessary to create a new route, your url's should look like `/statements/<statement_type>\new` or something similar.

I would also suggest you separate the key for your statement types and a user friendly description. Not use the description as your key. You can do this by providing an array of arrays to `options_for_select` or, probably better use something like `options_from_collection_for_select(statement_types, 'first', 'second')`